# how to change array format while getting both data are in array

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I have an array from the same db but different columns but i need both values in combine state

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [Student Name] => student_name
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Student ID] => student_id
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Marks 1] => maths
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [Mark 2] => english
        )
```

But I need values in format :

```
[0] => Array(
       [Student Name] => student_name
       [Student ID] => student_id
       [Marks 1] => maths
       [Mark 2] => english

)
```

Comment: And what have you tried in order to get your array in the desired format?

Comment: I think you are bit confused. What you are asking is so simple, Just pass your array to new array with index 0. e.g. `$new_array[0] = $my_array`

Comment: you have to describe you code then only we can help, you only mentioned the output here.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a `foreach`.

Something like

```
$sortedArray = array(); 

foreach($completeArray as $singleArray) {
    $sortedArray[] = $singleArray[0]; 
}
```

*I don't tested this, please don't blame me. It's just a sample.*

`$completeArray` is your result from your db.

I hope this will do the thing you want.